# Why do I need to use waitForAngular(false) & browser.sleep(3000)?

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, automated-tests, end-to-end

We have a website that is built 100% from Angular and I was asked to use Protractor to write an end to end testing. Now encountered a problem that if I do not use `waitForAngular(false)` and `browser.sleep(3000)` then my test fails even I used the `ExpectedCondition`.

So here is my Scenario:

In the login page, I can find all elements, send keys to the input box and login. But after login, it fails. It cannot find any element, click any element at all.

My Code looks like this.

```
describe("/profile", () => {
  let page: Profile;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    page = await login(Profile, user, login);
    await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(page.element));
    await navigate(path.profile)
  })

  afterAll(async () => {
    logout();
  })

  it("should have navigate to the page", async () => {
    expect(await browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("/profile");
  });

  it("should have correct page markup", async () => { 
// this test fails without waitForAngular(false)
// or browser.sleep(3000) in the navigation or OnPrepare in the config
    expect(await page.headerTitle.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    expect(await page.headerTitle.getText()).toContain("Profile")
  })
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post the error message & html source?

Comment: The error I get is ` - Failed: script timeout: elementHere was not received in 11 seconds`

Comment: @Joon-sooYoo, do you have a `setInterval`, `setTimeout` methods on your app? Maybe logging, audit or long-running, repeatedly executed asynchronous operations?

Comment: @Hidberg I tried using `setInterval` and `setTimeout` before. It sometimes passes the test, and sometimes it fails. Isn't using those two quite similar to using sleep but on a global scale?

Anyway, I did try doing a mockup test with the https://angularjs.org/ website. I did not use any sleep or waitForAngular to false. All my test passes and only took a few seconds. 

I think it's something to do with the angular site we have or something. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `browser.wait()` takes three parameters - function condition, timeout, message on failure. Only last one is optional. You forgot to specify timeout time in milliseconds, likely it causes your problem

Second, `waitForAngular` takes optional string as a description. Idk why you pass `false` to it

P.S.
I think you misunderstand major concepts about how to handle waiting in protractor

`browser.sleep(ms)` - is explicit wait, stops execution for number of ms specified as a parameter

`browser.wait()` - waits until the function passed to it returns true, or for the number of ms passed as a parameter. It's not an explicit wait. Also, its not going to wait indefinitely. You pass timeout time as argument, or it takes `jasmineNodeOpts.defaultTimeoutInterval` from your protractor.conf.js or default 30 seconds

Your `browser.sleep(ms)` causing performance issue of your tests. Avoid it in your tests

`browser.waitForAngular()` - very useful, it waits until your angular app completes all tasks behind scene, but it's included in each actions by default. So no usually no affects if you use 2,3 or 4 times. IMPORTANT, some apps are poorly built and always load something in a background, so your tests are either slow or unresponsive at all. This is why I always run tests with `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`, but it's super difficult to handle wait. As an advantage you get fast and reliable tests. And don't pass `false` to `waitForAngular`, it has no effect.

With that said, forget about `browser.sleep()` instead learn how to use `browser.wait`

if you're using `browser.sleep(3000)` you make your tests stop for 3 sec, but what if your next element is ready to be interacted with in 500ms?? so just say wait until element is present(visible(intractable(or whatever you want))), but no longer than 3 sec, and you end up having faster tests

Hope that answers your question

Comment: I was told not to add timeout time because it will explicitly wait for the second you put on it. So if I put `await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(page.element),5000,"error")` even though it already found the element in 1-2 seconds it will wait the full 5 seconds.

Like I mentioned above, if I did not use `waitForAngular(false)` after logging in. The spec that I wrote to find the element will fail. I cannot even click a button, even I had to use `browser.sleep(3000)`.

Comment: I already wrote like 80+ spec of our site, the problem is it takes about 34 mins to run all the tests. Now, the problem is I been using `waitForAngular` , `browser.sleep(3000)` and `explicitWait` . And I was told not to use any of that to make my test run faster, like maybe around 18-25 mins.

Our site is 100% angular, so that is why I am confused about why I need to use`waitForAngular(false)` to make my code work. If you have any suggestion please let me know.

Comment: We went on refactoring our login component and then create a reusable async function for `browser.wait` that uses for `visibilityOf` to find an element and `element.click()`. Then we also include a `DEFAULT_WAIT = 10000` .

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As I understood also from comments, on your app (which should be tested with protractor) you have `setInterval`, `setTimeout` or long-running and repeatedly executed asynchronous operations.

Before Protractor will perform any test specification, it tries to wait for the Angular 2 app to “synchronize”, i.e. to complete all outstanding operations. As per default, Protractor defines an 11 seconds timeout for this to happen.

As you have some "infinite" operations - synchronization fails and protractor stop execution with timeout error.

You may use [Zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js) to avoid this:

```
ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
        ngZone.run(() => {
            // async operation
        });
    }, 2500);
```

Investigate this with your devs together.

Source: https://christianliebel.com/2016/11/angular-2-protractor-timeout-heres-fix/